# Jenkins plugin - global settings disappear after a apply/save in GUI

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

Global settings(Configure System section in Manage jenkins) of a jenkins plugin will disappear in GUI after when we apply and save the setting.

We want to view the settings when ever we reopen Configure System section in Manage jenkins.Can somebody please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wich version are u using?

Comment: @totonho Jenkins ver. 2.107.2

Comment: Global settings is gone forever? when u save settings?

Comment: No @totonho, settings are getting passed to the build but those are not visible in the global settings once i enter and save it.

Comment: @totonho Can you please acknowledge for the above message

Comment: Are u using declarative pipeline? I think that you should elaborate better your answer.

Comment: NO @totonho, I am taking about Configure System section(global settings) in Manage jenkins.

Comment: I figured out what is the issue, my getters names are not correct as per java standards in the code. After fixing those i am able to view the global settings in the  jenkins UI.